# Oracle 11g see transaction or session start time

Tags: oracle, oracle-11g-r2, transaction, deadlock, transaction-log

I want to know when a session or transaction started. The deadlock file doesn't give me this information. Is there some logfile that keeps these records?

I've got a transaction id "TX-1234-abcd", a session number and some "DID 000-000ABCD" number.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the only way I am aware of is to use [Oracle logminer](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e22490/logminer.htm)

the archivelogs are used if a database was restored from a backup and must be rolled forward to a point in time where the database crashed. (almost) all information that written to the database therefore is contained in the redologs so that this roll forward can be done. Logminer can be used to analyze the contents of archivelogs (redologs). but using the logminer is very cumbersome. you need a database with dba privileges (it must not be the same databaase where your transaction was applied but of the same version an os system) and you need the archivelogs that contain your transaction. I am not sure if the details are well documented so i think you need a some knowledge about oracle internals and i think this is a job for an adventurous database administrator.

Answer (score 5):

Franz

The view [V$TRANSACTION](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B12037_01/server.101/b10755/dynviews_2149.htm) likely gives you the information you require. The transaction id is the XID column,

Comment: yeah thanks, but that are only the active ones. I'm trying to access old stuff.

Comment: you could try the "versions of" flashback query in that case.